# GUID Comparer error!

Tags: c++, visual-c++, guid

I have the following simple function written - an unordered map that takes in 2 GUIDS as the key and the value. However, I don think they have a GUID comparer defined, so it throws this error with al the GUID comparers that I have tried.

```
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<Objbase.h>
 typedef unordered_map<GUID, GUID, less_guid> Mymap;
 Mymap c1;

 int __cdecl wmain(int /*argc*/, __in_ecount(argc) WCHAR * /*argv[ ]*/)
 {
    GUID TargetC;
    GUID TargetA;
    CoCreateGuid(&TargetC); CoCreateGuid(&TargetA); 
    c1.insert(Mymap::value_type(TargetC,TargetA)); /
    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

This is the error that shows up-:
">c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xhash(154): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments"

I'm in dire need of a solution. I'd appreciate your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The third template parameter of `std::unordered_map` is a hash function, the fourth template parameter is a comparison function:

```
template<class Key,
         class T,
         class Hash = hash<Key>,
         class Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
         class Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> > >
class unordered_map;
```

You are passing `less_guid`, which sounds like a comparison function, as the third template parameter.